# How to change canvas rotation origin if I'm already using translate?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to build a bird-view game where the player moves front and back with the up and down arrow, with the left and right arrow rotating the page to control the direction. Here's what I have

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
var ctx = canvas1.getContext('2d');

function drawEnvironment(){
   //draw stuff
}
drawEnvironment();

var rotate = 0;
var top = 0;

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;

    if (code == 39) {
        rotate -= 5;
    }
    if (code == 37) {
        rotate += 5;
    }
    if (code == 38) {
        top += 5;
    }   
    if (code == 40) {
        top -= 5;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    ctx.save(); 
    ctx.translate(0,top);

    ctx.translate(150,150);
    ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * rotate);
    ctx.translate(-150,-150);

    drawEnvironment();
    ctx.restore();
 }
```

Problem with this is that once the character moves the rotation is no longer around its center, so I tried accounting for the value of TOP when rotating...

```
ctx.translate(0,top);
ctx.translate(150,150-top);
ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * rotate);
ctx.translate(-150,-150+top);
```

which fixes the rotation origin problem, but now moving forwards/backwards doesn't account for rotation anymore, since the translate happens after rotation.

Any ideas for what would be the best approach to tackle this?